# How do I connect to the Jungle 2.0 Network with dfuse API

Tags: testnet, dfuse

Where is the dfuse API endpoint to connect to the Jungle 2.0 Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.dfuse.io/en/blog/dfuse-supports-jungle-testnet-2.0

> How dfuse is supporting Jungle 2.0 Testnet
>
> dfuse API provides a REST and WebSocket API, which you can connect to
>   using dfuse. Read through the [documentation](http://docs.dfuse.io/#endpoints) to get started and apply
>   for your free API key.
>
> EOS Canada also offers standard endpoints for nodeos:
>
> RPC API: https://jungle.eoscanada.com P2P:
>   peering.jungle.eoscanada.com:9876
>
> Jungle 2.0 General Chain Info Chain
>   ID: e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473

The endpoints can be found in the documentation here: http://docs.dfuse.io/#endpoints

> Jungle Network Endpoints for the Jungle Network (chain ID:
>   e70aaab8...)
>
> Websocket wss://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/v1/stream
>   REST  https://jungle.eos.dfuse.io/

They also provide the following the endpoints:

> EOS Mainnet Endpoints for the EOS Mainnet (chain ID: aca376f2...)
>
> Websocket wss://mainnet.eos.dfuse.io/v1/stream
>   REST  https://mainnet.eos.dfuse.io/
>
> CryptoKylin Network Endpoints for the CryptoKylin Network (chain ID:
>   5fff1dae...)
>
> Websocket wss://kylin.eos.dfuse.io/v1/stream
>   REST  https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io/

*The dfuse API is available for multiple EOSIO networks. Should you need it on another network, contact us.*